# Google App Engine : Common way to implement sessioned API/ajax requests?

Tags: ajax, google-app-engine, session, cookies, access-token

I don't even understand how user session information is persisted across regular HTTP/S GET calls, and I mean the details, like *line by line* of code and data in the server/client exchanges. I basically get that it is a session object on the server containing what you need, and an id to that object contained in a 'cookie' WTHTI. That gets opaquely (to Javascript) passed back and forth with the server. Damn that untouchable cookie.

I would like to implement sessioned CRUD database endpoints in python/AppEngine. What's the best way to do the session persistence? (no frameworks,plugins, or ready-made solutions, I want to understand). I don't even know how the hell any of this is actually done in any app, but it's so common.

I guess something like a token one sends with each API call, but isn't that messy, just having a token lying around in the Javascript/DOM on the client side?

What about cookies, how the hell do cookies even work? This is such a blindspot for me, and it's so crucial. I have no idea why it's not transparent and easy to implement.

And if all we're doing is transferring an id back and forward to Ident the user, and call up the user's session object, what's the difference between a cookie and a (non edible) token?

Is it completely possible to just do user auth, transition to a session, just using tokens, or must one use cookies?

I'm implementing my own custom authent (on the back of webapp2_extras), and it's going to be on secure urls and with all the usual saltyhashed password precautions. But the 'token' and 'cookie' session part for all my AJAX machinery is still blowing my mind apart.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cookies:

1. Cookies are handled by browser internals, not by Javascript or DOM.
2. Cookies are very simple: just a name:value pair sent as a string in HTTP header
3. Principle of operation is very simple: server sends cookie to browser, after that browser sends cookie with every request to that server (this depends on cookie type and it's properties)
4. There are several types of cookies, but session cookies are session-bound: browser keeps them in memory and sends them until user closes the browser app.

Read more about it here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie

Sessions are a series of http requests coming from the same user. They are usually built by using cookies (there are other techniques), so sessions depend on cookies (but cookies do not depend on sessions).

Server sessions are an internal persistent storage bound to certain cookie, for example GAE on production uses cookie with name `ACSID` to track it's sessions. So when servers does not get a session cookie it assumes this is a new session and creates a new session cookie and sends it to client and creates the object storage tied to that session. Afterwards whenever server gets a session cookie it loads object storage bound to that cookie.

Note: cookies and sessions are not authentication: they can tell you that a series of requests come from the same user, but they don't tell you which user this is. This is the job of authentication, which you can roll your own (username-password based or similar) or you could use one of the available authentication protocols (OpenID, OAuth).

Qs:

- Yes, you can your own session tracking with "non-edible" token, provided that you control both server and client. OTOH browsers are standards based and they use cookies out-of-the-box to provide sessions (but you can still roll your own in JS).
- Best way to do session persistence: use an [existing session library for python](https://github.com/dound/gae-sessions/wiki/comparison-with-alternative-libraries). You can still roll your own for learning purposes, but for production you should stick with one of the tested solutions.